# How to limit number of size from arraylist before send to fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm setting data from json to fragment. I wanna limit datas before send to fragment.

**My code to get lists from arraylist:**

```
ArrayList<MyCustom> coming = new ArrayList<>(comingfromanywhere);
ArrayList<MyCustom> coming2 = new ArrayList<>(comingfromanywhere);

coming.removeAll(coming2);

if (coming.size() != 0) {
   Fragment fragment = ComingFragment.newInstance(comingFragment);
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   ft.add(R.id.frameComing, fragment);
   ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

**How I can limit if list size more than 300 from coming before send to fragment?**

**Best regards.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sublist with the condition to check the size of the incoming array, if you think the incoming array could be null, you can also add null pointer check.

```java
 ArrayList<MyCustom> coming2 = 
                new ArrayList<>(comingfromanywhere.size()>300?
                comingfromanywhere.sublist(0,299):comingfromanywhere);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a sublist on the arraylist:

```
        ArrayList<T> firstList = arrayList.subList(startingIndex, endingIndex)
```

Comment: I tired this but app is stopped with this error code: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 300

Comment: @Nina, you need to check the size of the incoming array

Comment: It means you don't have 300 elements in the array. You can add a check as such: if(arrayList.size() > 300) then do the sublist thing below

Comment: I have 20.000 elements in my arraylist :D